# How can output of runlevel be "1 S"?

Tags: centos, upstart, runlevel

When I switch from runlevel 3 to runlevel 1 on my CentOS 6 box the output of runlevel is `1 S`:

```
# runlevel
1 S
```

I'd expect the output to be `3 1`. It's not a big deal but I'm keen to understand the logic behind the output. The man page for runlevel mentions that the Upstart init daemon works differently from SysVinit but as far as I'm aware runlevels 1 and S are always identical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [runlevel(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/runlevel) manual page, `1` and `S` are distinct:

> Runlevel 1 is used to bring the system back down into single-user mode, after which the runlevel will be S.

and the CentOS 7 [runlevel](http://www.unix.com/man-page/centos/8/runlevel/) manual page (which deprecates the feature), says

> runlevel prints the previous and current SysV runlevel if they are known.

so `S` being *current*, and `1` being *previous* is consistent with the other version of the manual page.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at runlevel(8). I've now also learned (from the telinit man page) that it's possible to switch to runlevel S directly - but this wouldn't stop running processes. So that's what runlevel 1 does: it gracefully switches to single-user mode.